# Insert Formatted HTML into Excel sheet row by row

Tags: python, excel, xlwings, pyperclip

I have a rather odd use case that I'm having trouble solving. I have formatted HTML code (namely, HTML with colored text) that I want to preserve the formatting on and paste into Excel on a specified sheet. These documents can be rather long (e.g. few hundred rows), so putting them in one big cell isn't really a viable option (although I tried that as well and couldn't get it to work), and I think row by row is probably the best route.

I have been trying this, but it appears that xlwings only will respect the clipboard of xlwings; i.e. pyperclip copies it to the clipboard, but the paste fails since xlwings doesn't recognize anything being on the clipboard (said differently, if you do a .copy immediately before, it works, but it doesn't have the data I need!)

Looking for any help. This is just text, not an HTML table. I do know and recognize that this is an odd use case, but it is what it is....

```
#create new workbook
import xlwings as xl
import pyperclip

wb = xl.Book()

#read in html to string
with open('test.html', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

#copy the html to the clipboard so that the HTML format is correct?
pyperclip.copy(data)

#wb.sheets("Sheet1").range("A1").copy()    #this prevents the error, but doesn't have the data I need. Proves xlwings doesn't respect the pyperclip clipboard
wb.sheets("Sheet1").range("A1").paste() #fails since xlwings doesn't respect pyperclip clipboard
```

Simple html example that can be used for testing

```
<body>
    <p>Normal Text</p>
    <p style="color:red;">Red paragraph text</p>
    <p>Normal Text</p>
</body>
```

Said differently, I would like a way via Python to take the html above, which looks like this when rendered:

[image]

And put it into Excel, so that Excel looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't get how your code is supposed to work. You are reading the file into 'data' then reading the empty cell A1 in a new Excel Sheet and pasting to the same cell. How would that get the data into the Sheet (each line on a different row)?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; it’s missing a line where the data is copied to the clipboard via pyperclip; must have got dropped in a copy paste somehow. I’ll fix when I’m at computer next!

Comment: @moken, I updated with the missing pyperclip code, as well as a screenshot and some test html to hopefully make the problem clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just read the data and write line by line to the Sheet?

```
import xlwings as xl


#read in html to string
with open('Output.html', 'r') as file:
    #data = file.read()
    data = file.readlines()  # Html lines as separate lines

with xl.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xl.Book()

    ### Write each line to the next row in the Sheet down Column A
    for row, line in enumerate(data, 1):
        wb.sheets("Sheet1").range(f'A{row}').value = line
        wb.sheets("Sheet1").range(f'A{row}').api.WrapText = False

    wb.save('Output.xlsx')
```

**Update**
To do what you want per the update all you want to do is open the file as html and save it.

Assuming your html example has the name 'test.html'

```
<body>
    <p>Normal Text</p>
    <p style="color:red;">Red paragraph text</p>
    <p>Normal Text</p>
</body>
```

E.g. the following code will open the file in Excel and save as an XLSX.
That's all that is required to produce the Excel Sheet per your screenshot in the question.

```
import xlwings as xl


with xl.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xl.Book('test.html')

    wb.sheets.active.autofit()  # Autofit Column A if desired 

    wb.save('Output1.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I think the problem there is that the html colors won’t be respected, right? It would just be raw html and not rendered html, correct? I can give it a shot when home, but that was why I didn’t go that route, since I figured the raw HTML, not rendered HTML, is what would be inserted.

Comment: I have updated the answer given the additional detail.

Comment: Thank you; awesome trick I would have never thought of!! Accepted answer